# GNOME 3: bottom panel window order

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, gnome3

I have centos 7.1. At bottom panel opened windows (running applications) are represented (ex: openoffice, thunrderbird, terminal). Question one - How can I change the order of these opened windows (ex:terminal,openoffice, thunrderbird) as in centos 6 I did drag and drop but here I can't?

The strange thing is that I've noticed that their order suddenly changes when I lock the system and log in again. Question two - how can it be explained?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior (order changing) with gnome classic 3.16. Also, the order on the panel appears to be chronological (they show up in the order you open them).

Answer (score 2):

The tabs work in a chronological order of opening and active and let's say you have 4 applications 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' launched in the same order. Gnome3 will display this as A-B-C-D.

Now if you access B again, the order of recently active changes and will change to A-C-D-B. To see this in action now, follow the steps below:

Press `Alt` + `F2` and then type `r`, press `enter`.

Again to stress that this works purely chronologically, let the tabs which are alphabetically chosen as above be arranged on your panel as D-B-A-C and now you want them to be arranged as A-B-C-D. So maximise/open the apps in the same order (i.e. A-B-C-D) and

Press `Alt` + `F2` and then type `r`, press `enter`.